# Why would images in my Twitter Card posts disappear?

Tags: images, twitter, twitter-card

Wondering whether some other people are having the same issue as I.

I create posts on my WordPress website, go to Twitter and write a tweak about them, after a few, the Twitter Card shows as expected, including the picture. So it's all working just fine.

However, when I check my twitter feed some time later, many of those images are just gone. The page does not change in any way so the exact same twitter card definition (meta tags) appears in the page header.

Any idea why my images would disappear over time?

Note that if I go to the [Twitter Card Validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator), the image appears just fine and that will wake it and then it shows up in my feed as well, but I would think I should not have to do that to keep my images around?!